# Funções privadas via ajax - Code Igniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Estou utilizando o Code Igniter para criar um sistema web e para que o usuário não atualize a página perdendo que já está aberto eu utilizo todas as chamadas via ajax dentro de "módulos". O problema é que, se eu coloco uma função em um controlador como público o usuário pode chutar a URL e acessar a função sem permissão e se eu uso as funções como privadas, não consigo acessá-las através de chamadas em Ajax.

Alguém ai tem uma boa solução?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar `$this->input->is_ajax_request()` da classe [input](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html):

```
if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
   exit('No direct script access allowed');
}
```